# Once and for all: Is there or is there not a way to manipulate an image from another domain using IE9+

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, canvas, cors

Assuming I can set the HTTP headers on both domains, is there any way to draw an **image** using CORS (from another domain) onto a `canvas` element and extract it's bitmap using IE9 and/or IE10?

Internet Explorer prior to version 11 doesn't support the `crossOrigin` property of an `img` element and I couldn't get it to work simply by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the image response call. All the guides and past questions I came across offered only these two methods, so I couldn't find a solution that works for me.

So to be conclusive, is there a way or is there not?

Please provide an example if you know of a working method. Thanks in advance.

Notes:

- I can't proxy the image since the use of a CDN is required, in which case I have to use CORS
- My last resort is to decode the image into base64 and return it using JSONP, but I'm hoping to find a solution that will not require me to proxy the image in it's text form, thus saving two copies of the image on my CDN (and the user's local cache).

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely YES, you can get the rgba image data from an image across domains.

And as you've discovered, the key is that that "other" domain must be configured to allow access.  That access can be limited to a few specified domains (white-hatted access) or it can be opened to allow open access to any anonymous request.  Here's a link on how to set cross-domain access on your server: http://enable-cors.org/

You must also specifically request cross-origin sharing on the client-side. This is done by setting the crossOrigin="anonymous" property on the html Image object.  Most browsers (including IE9+) support crossOrigin requests.

**So, YES...**

If the server-side is properly configured and the client-side is properly requesting...you will be able to manipulate your cross-domain image using context.getImageData and canvas.toDataURL.

Here's example code successfully making a cross-origin request for an image (dropbox.com has properly set its server headers to allow anonymous access):

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Xpy53/#base

```
// create a JS image object

var XDomainImage=new Image();

// ask the server for anonymous access to this image

XDomainImage.crossOrigin="anonymous";

// when the image is loaded...

XDomainImage.onload=function(){
    canvas.width=XDomainImage.width;
    canvas.height=XDomainImage.height;
    ctx.drawImage(XDomainImage,0,0);

    // use getImageData to grab the pixel data

    var data=ctx.getImageData(50,35,1,1).data;
    var red=data[0];
    var green=data[1];
    var blue=data[2];
    alert("The image pixel at [50,30] is rgb("+red+","+green+","+blue+")");
}

// dropbox has properly set its headers to allow anonymous access

XDomainImage.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/colorhouse.png";
```

As far as "for once and for all" ... this question is often asked and it will be again.

Comment: I've opened your code example on IE10 and this is what I got: "SCRIPT5022: SecurityError show, line 48 character 5"

Comment: Also, according to MSDN the `crossOrigin` property is only supported on IE11, which could explain why it works on any browser other then IE10- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn254950(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use of `XDomainRequest`? Perhaps provide a working code example? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here's a link that fairly well presents why XDomainRequest is needed and how to detect the need for it: http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/use-cors-with-all-modern-browsers Be sure you check this implementing code near the bottom of the post: https://github.com/dkastner/jquery.iecors

Comment: Using `XDomainRequest` I can fetch an image but only as binary. From what I've gathered the string returned to JavaScript by `responseText` will be terminated at the first null value and `XDomainRequest` has only a `responseText` and no `responseBody`. So far I couldn't get it to work.